# Can reading a value of a variable kill the definition of the variable?

Tags: compilers, data-flow-analysis

I was going through the concept of *reaching definitions* from the red dragon book.

The authors define *reaching definitions* as follows:

> Definition: We say a definition $d$ reaches a point $p$ if there is a path from the point immediately following $d$ to $p$, such that $d$ is not "killed" along that path.

Then the authors consider a flow graph and explain the definition with an example as follows:

> [image: A flow graph]
>
> For example, both the definitions `i:=m-1` and `j:=n` in block $B_1$ in Fig. above reach the beginning of block $B_2$, as does the definition `j:=j-1`, provided there are no assignments to or ***reads of `j`*** in $B_4$, $B_5$, or the portion of $B_3$ following that definition.

I can understand that in $B_4$, $B_5$, or the portion of $B_3$ following that definition `j:=j-1` if there is an assignment to `j` then the definition $d_5$ is killed. But what problem shall be there if there is simply a **read of the value `j`**? How does it kill the definition $d_5$ and prevent it from reaching the top of $B_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the errata sheet for the 1st edition (this came from the first ed, right? That diagram is so 1980's) but it sure looks like a mistake. The 2nd edition says

> "We say a definition d reaches a point p if there is a path from the
> point immediately following d to p such that d is not "killed" along
> that path. We kill a definition of a variable x if there is any other
> definition of x anywhere along the path. ... A definition of a
> variable x is a statement that assigns, or may assign, a value to x"

So I agree with your doubts, pretty certainly a read can't kill (just reading a variable can't change program state).

Comment: Yes, this is from the first ed.